# What is the actual data type of the @cleartext (2nd) param of SQL Server's EncryptByKey(..) function?

Tags: t-sql, types, parameters

Pointedly what I'm asking below is: **What is the *actual data type* of the @cleartext parameter of this SQL function? >> ENCRYPTBYKEY (..) -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx**

(If you read below this line you can follow the history and reasoning. I think it's trickier than it first appears.)

---

The SQL Server documentation states the **@cleartext (2nd) parameter of the [EncryptByKey(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361(SQL.90).aspx) function** can accept a number of various types:

> EncryptByKey (@key_GUID , **@cleartext** [, @add_authenticator, @authenticator] )
>
> **@cleartext**
>  Is a variable of type
>   **nvarchar, char, varchar, binary,
>   varbinary, or nchar** that contains data
>   that is to be encrypted with the key.

**^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  - - - - - But what is its actual declared data type? ...**

If I were to create a custom function (totally separate from the EncryptByKey example given above) **what actual data type do I give a custom parameter so it will accept all those same types in the same manner?**

**Edit 1:** I'm actually wrapping the SQL EncryptByKey function in a custom
 UDF function and I want to recreate the same
 parameter types to pass through to
 it. This is the reasoning behind my want to create exact same params by type.

**Edit 2:** If I try using `sql_variant` it results in the error

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   EncryptWrapper, Line 17 Argument data
>   type sql_variant is invalid for
>   argument 2 of EncryptByKey function.

**Edit 3:**

Here's my custom wrapper function - and the direct problem. What should the data type of @cleartext be for direct pass through to EncryptByKey?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[EncryptWrapper]
(
 @key_GUID uniqueidentifier,
 @cleartext -- ???????????  <<< WHAT TYPE ????????????????
 @add_authenticator int = 0,
 @authenticator sysname = NULL
)
RETURNS varbinary(8000)
AS
BEGIN

    -- //Calling a SQL Server builtin function. 
    -- //Second param @cleartext is the problem. What data type should it be?
 Return EncryptByKey(@key_GUID, @cleartext, @add_authenticator, @authenticator)

END
```

Note: I shouldn't have to use CAST or CONVERT - I only need to use the proper data type for my @cleartext param.

**Edit 4**: Discovered the EncryptByKey(..) @cleartext parameter is **not the following types**:

- `sql_variant`- raises error when passed
- `varbinary`- too restrictive- doesn't allow passing of the text types otherwise accepted by EncryptByKey(..)
- `sysname`, `nvarchar`, `varchar`- weird behaviour- tends to take only the first character of the argument text or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENCRYPTBYKEY() almost certainly isn't written in vanilla T-SQL. It doesn't need to follow T-SQL data typing rules.

That said, if you want to write a wrapper for it, use SQL_VARIANT for the @cleartext parameter, just as KM suggested.

If ENCRYPTBYKEY() is not sensitive to the max length of @cleartext, you could munge all CHAR/VARCHARs to VARCHAR(8000), and all NCHAR/NVARCHARs to NVACHAR(4000).

Otherwise you may be SOL: any data type conversion that respects maximum length--eg, CHAR(10) vs CHAR(20)--will require dynamic SQL, so you would have to write it as a stored procedure, rather than a function. At that point, it's not really a wrapper anymore.

Comment: I was able to wrap it in multiple functions: EncryptNVarchar(..), EncryptVarchar(..), EncryptNbinary(..). However I believe you're correct that it doesn't have to follow standard SQL rules - Microsoft didn't eat their own dog food when writing that function.

Answer (score 2):

try sql_variant:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[yourFunction]
(
     @InputStr      sql_variant   --can not be varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)
)
returns
varchar(8000)

BEGIN
    --can use SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType') to determine given datatype

    --do whatever you want with @inputStr here
    RETURN CONVERT(varchar(8000),@InputStr)  --key is to convert the sql_varient to something you can use

END
GO
```

the key is to convert the sql_varient to something you can use within the function.  you can use IF statements and check the BaseType and convert the sql_varient back into the native data type

**EDIT**
here is an example of how to get the original datatype:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[yourFunction]
(
     @InputStr      sql_variant   --can not be varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)
)
returns
varchar(8000)

BEGIN
    DECLARE @Value varchar(50)
    --can use SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType') to determine given datatype

    --do whatever you want with @inputStr here
    IF @InputStr IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @value= 'was null'
    END
    ELSE IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType')='char'
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        SET @value= 'char('+CONVERT(varchar(10),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'MaxLength '))+') - '+CONVERT(varchar(8000),@InputStr)
    END
    ELSE IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType')='datetime'
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        SET @value= 'datetime - '+CONVERT(char(23),@InputStr,121)
    END
    ELSE IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType')='nvarchar'
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        SET @value= 'nvarchar('+CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'MaxLength '))/2)+') - '+CONVERT(varchar(8000),@InputStr)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        set @value= 'unknown!'
    END

    RETURN  @value

END
GO
```

test it out:

```
DECLARE @x char(5), @z int, @d datetime, @n nvarchar(27)
SELECT @x='abc',@d=GETDATE(),@n='wow!'
select [dbo].[yourFunction](@x)
select [dbo].[yourFunction](@d)
select [dbo].[yourFunction](@z)
select [dbo].[yourFunction](@n)
```

test output:

```
-------------------------------------
char(5) - abc  

(1 row(s) affected)


-------------------------------------
datetime - 2010-02-17 15:10:44.017

(1 row(s) affected)


-------------------------------------
was null

(1 row(s) affected)


-------------------------------------
nvarchar(27) - wow!

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: sql_variant results in the error message I put in 'Edit 2' of the question. I need to perform a direct pass through, so I need the exact same data type used by EncryptByKey's second param.

Comment: I've edited my answer too, within the wrapper function, CONVERT the sql_variant input parameter into a text type before passing it to EncryptByKey function.

Comment: That's a workaround to my issue, and it's plausible. However the real problem is I need to not modify the data type (through convert or cast) but to pass it directly through to the second param of the SQL EncryptByKey function which accepts multiple text data types - therefore I want to accept the same into a type.  ... I added an Edit 3 to the question showing the exact problem.

Comment: sql_variant is a wrapper datatype. your char, varchar, nchar, etc gets passed into the function, but within the function the parameter is an sql_variant.  your EncryptByKey doesn't take the sql_variant data type, so you'll need to convert it back to the original type passed into the function.  you can do this by using the SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY() function.  if you don't want to do this, then there is no way to acheive your goal using TSQL.  You could look into using a CLR.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but the @cleartext parameter won't accept sql_variant arg; however it accepts multiple text data types, so logically it must be defined as some data type other than sql_variant. We know all parameters are defined with an actual data type (implicit or explicit). Do you know how to find out the actual data type of that parameter?

Comment: +1 for the provided workaround that I've decided to use in lieu of not knowing the actual data type of the 2nd param, which may turn out to be something intangible because it's a builtin function.