# Encrypt Column (Full text Search)

Tags: sql-server

I need your help.

I have the following table, (Example).

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
       ID INT,
       XML_DATA TEXT
)
```

The  column  XML_DATA is configured with Full Text Search and the datatype is TEXT (Is wrong, i now). In this column information is stored in XML format.

I need encrypt  this column to users don't see, bat I can't because is type TEXT and exists Full Text Search.

I added another column:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST
ADD EncryptCol VARBINARY(MAX)
```

And then run this command:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY S_Key DECRYPTION
BY CERTIFICATE EncryptCert
UPDATE TEST
SET EncryptCol = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('S_Key'),XML_DATA)
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY S_Key
```

And then an error:

Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 2 of EncryptByKey function.
How can i encrypt this column?

_Thanks

Keny Maciel

Comment: Is there much point having a column with the encrypted text if the column with the plaintext is sitting right there in the same record?

Comment: I just need find way to users don't see this column, only the application

Comment: Does the application come in under different user credentials (e.g. a website that doesn't do pass-through authentication)? If so, manage this through permissions. That is, DENY select permission on that column to anyone but the application user.

Comment: The application is using the same credentials that users use (This is so bad).

Comment: Found another question asking about the datatype of that second parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283477/what-is-the-actual-data-type-of-the-cleartext-2nd-param-of-sql-servers-encry